# ms-access phone table design for multiple individuals with multiple addresses

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

## How do I design tables and relationships for multiple contact information, for several individuals?

The contact information is related to each other, especially addresses and phone numbers.

The goal is to make a structure which works for as many scenarios as possible. *clients, users, students, supervisors and employees* or other categories used with labels.

The contact information one wants to, or has to, keep track of in the database for the company or organisation can differ quite a lot, depending on what they work with.

This is something I have a hard time tackling, and the way to solve this is very divided over the net.

*Other sources at the bottom.*

---

- Each client /employee /student can have one or more addresses, like privet and work addresses.
- Each client /employee /student can have one or more phone numbers, like mobile, work, private (and fax)

  1. An employee and have one or more pages as well.
- Each client /employee /student can have more then one email addresses, like private and work.

---

### My current table design. (Related tables)

**tblClients:**

- ClientID  (PK)(Indexed no duplicates)
- KlientKey (security number or personal ID)(Indexed no duplicates)
- FirstName
- LastName

**tblAddress:**

- AddressID (PK)(Indexed no duplicates)
- ClientID (FK)(indexed with duplicates)
- CategoryID (FK)(ID = 1 or 4)
- Address
- City
- ZIP

**tblNumber:**

- NumberID (PK)(Indexed no duplicates)
- ClientID (FK)(indexed with duplicates)
- AddressID (FK)(indexed with duplicates)(No Table relations, experimental.)
- Category(FK)(ID = 2 or 3 or 5)
- Number

**tblEmail:**

- EmailID (PK)(Indexed no duplicates)
- ClientID (FK)(Indexed with duplicates)
- CategoryID (FK)(ID = 1 or 4)
- Email

**tblCategorys:**

- CategoryID (PK)(Indexed no duplicates)
- Category (1; Private, 2; Phone, 3; Mobile, 4; Work, 5; Fax)

---

This structure generates duplicates whenever the data is listed in a form, query or report. And the issue is related to phone numbers and addresses. 
The conflict occurs whenever two addresses or phone numbers with the under the same category has to be displayed in a list. Well, that is what believe.

As you can see below the contact information is duplicated. I want to prevent this from happening. Plus, I want to prevent a phone number to be displayed on a record which doesn't have the displayed phone number.
These reports only shows private addresses, to the household(s) with other words, if I make any sense here. (Img is removed duo reputation limit.)

As shown in the picture is how i want the reports look like.
I achieve this result with the new tbl design, new queries and a little vba. This is just experimental nothing more.
[Img 2 -  experimental](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQngs.jpg)

Clients & Email

```
SELECT tblClients.ClientID, 
       tblClients.ClientKey, 
       [tblClients].[LastName] & ",  " & [tblClients].[Firstname] AS Klient,            
       tblClients.Startdate, 
       tblClients.EndDate, 
       [qryList(PrivateEmails)].Email, 
       tblClients.LastName
FROM tblClients 
LEFT JOIN [qryList(PrivateEmails)] 
     ON tblClients.ClientID = [qryList(PrivateEmails)].ClientID;
```

Addresses & Phone numbers

```
SELECT tblAddress.ClientID,
       tblAddress.Address, 
       tblAddress.ZIP, 
       tblAddress.City, 
       tblNumber.Number, 
       tblAddress.CategoryID, 
       tblNumber.AddressID, 
       tblNumber.CategoryID

FROM tblAddress 
LEFT JOIN tblNumber 
     ON tblAddress.AddressID = tblNumber.AddressID
WHERE (((tblAddress.CategoryID) 
      Is Null Or (tblAddress.CategoryID)=1) 
         AND ((tblNumber.AddressID) 
      Is Null Or (tblNumber.AddressID)>=1) 
         AND ((tblNumber.CategoryID) 
      Is Null Or (tblNumber.CategoryID)=2));
```

Final query

```
SELECT Clients.*, [qryAddress&PhoneNuber(Private)].*
FROM Clients 
LEFT JOIN [qryAddress&PhoneNuber(Private)] 
     ON Clients.ClientID = [qryAddress&PhoneNuber(Private)].ClientID;
```

vba for populate the addressID in tblnumbers, triggerd when the user saves changes in a form when a new record is added or edited.

```
' A Dynamic array would be usful whenever multiple addresses and phone numbers is added as private.
   If IsNull(varAddressID) = 0 Then
        If Me.frmAddress.Form.txtCategoryID = 1 Then
            If Me.frmNumber.Form.txtCategoryID = 2 Then
                Me.frmNumber.Form.txtAddressID = Me.frmAddress.Form.txtAddressID
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

---

**This is the sql qry i use when only want to see the private contact information.**

```
SELECT    tblClients.ClientKey,
          [tblClients].[LastName] & ".  " & [tblClients].[FirstName] AS Klient,
          tblClients.Startdate,
          tblClients.EndDate,
          [qryList(NumberPrivate)].Number,
          [qryList(PrivateAddresses)].Address,
          [qryList(PrivateAddresses)].ZIP,
          [qryList(PrivateAddresses)].City, 
          [qryList(PrivateEmails)].Email 
FROM ((
LEFT JOIN [qryList(PrivateEmails)] 
       ON tblClients.ClientID = [qryList(PrivateEmails)].
LEFT JOIN [qryList(PrivateAddresses)] 
       ON tblClients.ClientID = [qryList(PrivateAddresses)].
LEFT JOIN [qryList(NumberPrivate)] 
       ON tblClients.ClientID = [qryList(NumberPrivate)].ClientID 
WHERE  ((([qryList(NumberPrivate)].CategoryID) Is Null 
                 Or ([qryList(NumberPrivate)].CategoryID)=2) 
    AND (([qryList(PrivateAddresses)].CategoryID) Is Null 
                 Or ([qryList(PrivateAddresses)].CategoryID)=1) 
    AND (([qryList(PrivateEmails)].CategoryID) Is Null
                 Or ([qryList(PrivateEmails)].CategoryID)=1))
ORDER BY  tblClients.ClientKey DESC, 
          [tblClients].[LastName] & ".  " & [tblClients].[FirstName] DESC,
          tblClients.Startdate,
          tblClients.EndDate DESC;
```

**Other sources with the same or similar topic:**

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic637723-361-1.aspx

[Normalize or Denormalize: Store Contact Details (Phone Numbers) in separate Table? Search Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197301/normalize-or-denormalize-store-contact-details-phone-numbers-in-separate-tabl)

Comment: You mention that `ClientID` -- in the tables `tblAddress`, `tblPhone`, and `tblEmail` -- is indexed without duplicates. That seems wrong. The same `ClientID`should be allowed to occur several times.

Comment: Oh my bad, it's indexed with duplicates, totaly missed i wrote "Indexed no duplicates". Thx for the head ups. :)

Comment: Please edit your question to correct this. Could you add some queries you do for your output? Because the problem you seem to have is not related to your data model -- it is well designed.

Comment: The question has been updated,

Comment: Your SELECT query is missing at least tblClients in the FROM clause. And can you try to format the WHERE clause better, to make the logic visible?

Comment: `qryList(PrivateEmails)` suggests that this query already filters by category and only returns private addresses. Why do you filter again for `([qryList(PrivateEmails)].CategoryID)=1)` in your query?

Comment: 1: I'll try to format the query better and correct what i have missed.
2: Not sure way i filter again, i guess i forgot i had a filter in the sub query.

3: I'm also trying a different approach with adding the AddressID to the to a record in the number table. So a private number and private address will end up on the same line in the report.

I'll pass the addressID with vba from a form when the user saves a record where a new record has been added or an existing record has been edited.
@Andre

Comment: *"3: I'm also trying a different approach with adding the AddressID to the to a record in the number table."* - That would be a bad idea. Your data structures are good, don't ruin them. Work on the output queries / forms / reports instead.

Comment: I updated your question a bit, notably indenting the SQL query so it becomes more readable. Please note however that this SQL query has several syntax errors (opening brackets after `from` are never closed, missing base table right after `from`, fields missing in `on` clause). Could you please fix those errors, keeping the indentation as it is?

Comment: The problem of duplication is clear and a logical consequence of how you query (not of the data model). Based on the screenshot you have provided, could you provide the ***desired*** output on exactly the same data? That way we know what you actually expect. The thing is that your phone numbers, emails and addresses have no direct connection to each other, so how do you determine which should be combined on the same line, and which not (to avoid duplication)?

Comment: I noticed you changed my question and it looks much cleaner now. 
I tend to write more the necessary sometimes.

I added a screenshot with the outcome i **desire**. The date is the same, the only difference is the amount of clients because i did some tests. I know you guys said the table structure is good and it is related to the data output, but i wanted to try this idea. experiment a little and see how it works.

Then i'm not sure how to filter the first query to achieve my goal.
@trincot

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. What is Reg and AvgReg? It is not in your data model? And why are there different values of AvgReg for the same person? Also, is there a reason why you put phone 0304 50 51 78 on the same line as Götavägen 12, and don't (for instance) put it next to Strandvägen 4? Is there a way to determine which phone number belongs with which address? Also, the email address repeats for the first person. Is that what you want? What if a person has 2 email addresses and 3 phone numbers? Which phone number will go with which email address, and which email address repeats?

Comment: The Reg and AvReg is dates, a starting date and end date. These dates is mostly for statistics. They are also related to a deeper level in the system i haven't shared, because i thought i was not necessary. among with a few objects in the client table.

Comment: It is with this experimental model i'm determining which phone number and address are related to each other. But an email address don't have this relation.

If a person has 2 email addresses and 3 phone numbers the non private date will be filtered out + mobile numbers, then if a phone number and address has been related to each other they will be on the same row. 
If not they will be on separate rows.

However, if it would help i could share the db, i'll just have to finish the language control.
@trincot

Comment: I don't follow the logic on how you decide to put things on the same line. What if someone has 10 phone numbers and 5 address and 15 email addresses? I don't really understand how you want to represent that, and how you would decide which phone number should appear on the same line as some address and some email address... Could you provide a clear and explicit rule for that?

Comment: I'll have a version of the db uploaded later today so you can take a closer look if you want to. To be honest i don't know how i want to link them to make the most out of it. Plus i have to add a separate column with the mobile number next to the phone number column now. The local number still have to be linked but the mobile number and Email number don't. And i don't if i can make the number table to split phone & mobile numbers to two different columns with a query. it feels like this project is spinning away a little to much.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is good based on the data you want to store.

The question is more about the output -- how can I query the data so it doesn't show duplicate rows when I don't want to.

For this question there are many answers depending on what you are trying to do.  (i.e. Group Values on a Report (usual solution), Concatenate emails into a single row, Grab the max or min value of the sub objects, etc.)

I would recommend post another question with your query and any problems that you are seeing.

Comment: Basically, this. For forms, additional options are subforms and list boxes. In both cases, the related data (emails, phone numbers) isn't included in the main query, they are record/row sources of the subforms/list boxes. @Tobias Olsson

Comment: So it sounds like you are all set.  Your data model supports everything you describe.  If the sub-data is not included in the main query for the form, it won't duplicate.  You just use it when you need it.  Go ahead and start developing the forms and let us know if you run into any issues.